# collections.Counter for csv file and updating blank cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I am importing data from a csv file; and trying to determine a user type. In specific, I am using the python module collections.

My data set has blank fields thus when I execute the following script `type_of_users=user_data.most_common()` I get the following result:

The type of users are :

```
[('Subscriber', 269149), ('Customer', 30159), ('', 692)]
```

Is there a way to update the `('',692)` with `('Unknown User Type',692)`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension on the results of `.most_common()` after reading the file:

```
>>> type_of_users = [('Subscriber', 269149), ('Customer', 30159), ('', 692)]

>>> type_of_users = [(i, j) if i else ('Unknown User Type', j)
...                  for i, j in type_of_users]

>>> type_of_users
[('Subscriber', 269149), ('Customer', 30159), ('Unknown User Type', 692)]
```

This takes advantage of the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) that empty sequences ('') are considered False while non-empty strings are considered True.

Note that there are a number of other objects that will also evaluate in this way, so if you need to be more explicit, you should use `if i != ''`.

Comment: In case someone is wondering how to apply this to non-empty strings, this case could be re-written as `type_of_users = [(i, j) if i == '' else ('Unknown User Type', j) for i, j in type_of_users]`. You could swap the condition to whatever you need.